# Large set of data in listview crashing the android app

Tags: android, listview

Hi I need to manage the large set of data in Listview in android app. The list items may be around 250 or more than that. Now my problem is when I scroll the listview it crashes the app due more items. But the listview will working fine when the items are less than 100.

Please help me to solve this.

This is my Error Log.

```
02-13 06:43:07.320: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1776): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:577)
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:445)
android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:738)
android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1869)
android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:659)
android.widget.ScrollView.setOverScrollMode(ScrollView.java:1487)
android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:365)
android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:94)
android.widget.ScrollView.<init>(ScrollView.java:155)
android.widget.ScrollView.<init>(ScrollView.java:151)
```

And my `getView()` is

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    final int pos = position;
    views = null;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    views = (RelativeLayout) layoutInflator.inflate(
            R.layout.guest_list_item, null);

    final CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) views.getChildAt(0);
    // Log.d("", "CheckBox Pos "+position);
    chk.setId(position);

    TextView txtView = (TextView) views.getChildAt(1);

    TextView txtView2 = (TextView) views.getChildAt(2);
    TextView txtView3 = (TextView) views.getChildAt(3);

    final TextView txtView4 = (TextView) views.getChildAt(4);
    TextView txtView5 = (TextView) views.getChildAt(6);
    txtView5.setId(position);

    // Log.d("", "Button Pos "+position);
    txtView4.setId(position);

    txtView4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, InfoScreen.class);
            intent.putExtra("IDVALUE", arTempId.get(txtView4.getId()));
            intent.putExtra("IDVALUE", arrayListId.get(position));

            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            // System.out.println(v + "##########" + " " + v.getId());
            // System.out.println(v + "##########" + " " +
            // arTempId.get(txtView4.getId()));
            // System.out.println(v + "##########" + " " +
            // chickinlist.get(txtView4.getId()));
        }
    });
    Log.e("", "****************************************************** ");
    // Log.v("", "Adapter arr pos " + pos);
    // Log.v("", "Adapter arr position " + position);
    Log.v("", "Adapter arr size " + arrayListFirstName.size());
    Log.v("", "Passsing arr size " + chickinlist.size());

    for (int dd = 0; dd < arrayListFirstName.size(); dd++) {
        if (position == dd) {
            // Log.d("", "Passsing arr size " + chickinlist.size());
            Boolean result = chickinlist.get(position);
            // Log.d("", "After " + result);
            if (result == true) {
                chk.setChecked(true);
                arrCheckedItems.add(position);
                views.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_checked);

            } else {
                chk.setChecked(false);
                arrUnCheckedItems.add(position);
                views.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_unchecked);

            }

            txtView.setText(arrayListFirstName.get(position));
            txtView2.setText(arrayListLastName.get(position));
            txtView3.setText("(" + arrayListGuests.get(position) + ")");
            if (arrayCustomOne.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase("0")
                    || arrayCustomOne.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase(null)
                    || arrayCustomOne.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase(
                            "(null)")) {
                txtView5.setText("");
            } else {
                txtView5.setText(arrayCustomOne.get(position));
            }

        }

    }

    chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            mySqliteAdapter.openToWrite();

            sId = arrayListId.get(chk.getId());
            // Log.d("Adapter",
            // "Checked Temp Id "+arTempId.get(chk.getId()));
            Log.d("",
                    "Position " + chk.getId() + "tempid "
                            + arTempId.get(chk.getId()));

            if (isChecked) {

                chk.setChecked(true);
                arrCheckedItems.add(position);
                strAlertValue = "1";
                sCheckIn = "1";
                strExe = "update ticket_details set checkin_status=1 where tempid="
                        + arTempId.get(chk.getId());
                mySqliteAdapter.executeCheckQurey(strExe);
                if (Util.getInstance(context).isTabletDevice()) {
                    buttonView
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tablet_list_item_check);
                } else {
                    buttonView
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_checked);
                }

                new CheckInUpdate().execute();
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);
                builder.create();
                builder.setMessage(arrayListFirstName.get(chk.getId())
                        + " " + arrayListLastName.get(chk.getId())
                        + " has been checked in.");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                // myGuestList = new GuestListScreen();

                                //
                                // // myGuestList.ListUpdate();

                                //Intent intentNavGuestList = new Intent(
                                //context, GuestListScreen.class);
                                //intentNavGuestList
                                //                                          .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                                //context.startActivity(intentNavGuestList);

                                dialog.dismiss();

                            }

                        }).show();

                // Log.d("", "ID = " + buttonView.getId());

            }
            if (!isChecked) {

                sCheckIn = "0";
                strAlertValue = "0";

                // views.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_unchecked);
                strExe = "update ticket_details set checkin_status=0 where tempid="
                        + arTempId.get(chk.getId());

                mySqliteAdapter.executeCheckQurey(strExe);

                if (Util.getInstance(context).isTabletDevice()) {
                    buttonView
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tablet_list_item_uncheck);
                } else {
                    buttonView
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_unchecked);
                }
                new CheckInUpdate().execute();


                Intent intentNavGuestList = new Intent(context,
                        GuestListScreen.class);
                intentNavGuestList
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                context.startActivity(intentNavGuestList);

                // Toast.makeText(context, "check release",
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                // .show();
                // new CheckInUpdate().execute();

            }

        }
    });

    return views;

}
```

Comment: please post the getView method of your adapter.

Comment: Having more than 250 items in a listview won't crash the application, post your logcat and your code may be we can help you then.

Comment: show us getView method code and your data array structure. you did something wrong )

Comment: If your listView contains images and videos then I can say we are on the same page. How i solved this issue: I used a scroll function in a layout and inflated views in it. It goes up to 250. At almost 300 it crashes. It works as a list view. Load images and videos in it also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holder pattern is a right answer.It will be better if you implement "Pagination" pattern for listview. Show next items when listview scrolled to end. Also avoid to do long running task in Adapter. Put data and adapter separate. Please see use  notifyDataSetChanged () method.

Answer (score 1):

Guess - You are not re-using views . 

Try using the View Holder -Here are some links - 

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html
http://vsvydenko.blogspot.in/2011/06/android-use-viewholder.html
http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=166

Suggestion - 
 Make your adapter implement **OnClickListener** and  **OnCheckedChangeListener** .

```
public class YourAdapter  implements OnCheckedChangeListener, OnClickListener....
```

And then handle these events separately by -

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Do your stuff here

}
```

Like wise for **OnCheckedChangeListener**.

This way the code will have better readibility  and easy to debug.

Comment: Thanks now the scrolling working smooth but OutOfMemory error still occurs .

Comment: I know it's old, but I wouldn't use an OnCheckedChangeListener in a ListView when Views are being re-used... Every time you scroll the views will be re-used and their checked state will change, which will call that listener. You're much better of using OnClick and saving the clicked state within the data object.